# Magento 2: Get value from Cron system.xml

Tags: magento2, configuration, controllers, system.xml

I would like to take the value of the ahead schedule of this system.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="system">
        <group id="cron" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Cron (Scheduled Tasks)</label>
            <comment>For correct URLs generated during cron runs please make sure that Web &gt; Secure and Unsecure Base URLs are explicitly set. All the times are in minutes.</comment>
            <group id="template" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Cron configuration options for group: </label>
                <field id="schedule_generate_every" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Generate Schedules Every</label>
                </field>
                <field id="schedule_ahead_for" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Schedule Ahead for</label>
                </field>
                <field id="schedule_lifetime" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Missed if Not Run Within</label>
                </field>
                <field id="history_cleanup_every" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>History Cleanup Every</label>
                </field>
                <field id="history_success_lifetime" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Success History Lifetime</label>
                </field>
                <field id="history_failure_lifetime" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Failure History Lifetime</label>
                </field>
                <field id="use_separate_process" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Use Separate Process</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

I tried this command in a controller

```
$scheduleAheadFor = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/cron/schedule_ahead_for', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

but it did not work. Someone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing the `template` part from the config path.
Try this:

`$scheduleAheadFor = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/cron/template/schedule_ahead_for', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);`

Comment: is the first thing that I thought too. I tried $ this-> scopeConfig-> getValue ('system / cron / template / schedule_ahead_for', Magento Store ScopeInterface :: SCOPE_STORE); but returns null.

Comment: You need to replace `template` with your cron's group id

Comment: It worked! thanks @Tsita